# Apacha HttpClient configuration

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm currently using `RestTemplate` backed by Apache http client 4.5.6 in my web server for making http requests.  My `HttpClient` configuration is as follows:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(httpConfigurationProperties.getConnection().getMaxTotal());
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(httpConfigurationProperties.getConnection()

        return HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig
                    .custom()
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout((int) httpConfigurationProperties.getTimeout().getConnectionRequestTimeout().toMillis())
                    .setConnectTimeout((int) httpConfigurationProperties.getTimeout().getConnectTimeout().toMillis())
                    .setSocketTimeout((int) httpConfigurationProperties.getTimeout().getReadTimeout().toMillis())
                    .build())
                .setRetryHandler(StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler.INSTANCE)
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .build();
```

When I make a HTTP GET, once in a while i see this:

> I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing
>   request to {s}->: Connection reset

I have read in another post that this is caused by server(that I'm sending request to) closing the connection without informing client. And `StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler` was able to retry it. But HTTP POST methods are not retried because they are not idempotent operations. But is there a configuration that can avoid this connection reset in first place?

And I have tried using `evictExpiredConnections` and does not help. Will setting `connectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(20000)` help validating connection before using?

Before using apache http client I used `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` in `RestTemplate` and I never faced connection reset issues. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: Yes, setting evictIdleConnections to a lower value helped.